# How do I delete an entire chat, and not just the last message in telegram with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

It happens that I have this:

```
def clear (self, update, context):
      context.bot.delete_message (chat_id = message.chat_id, message_id = message.message_id)
```

But that only serves to delete the last message of the chat, but I want to delete the entire chat, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clear(self, update, context):
    new_message_id = message.message_id
    while new_message_id > 1:
        try:
            context.bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.chat_id, message_id=new_message_id)
        except Exception as error:
            print(f'Message_id does not exist: {new_message_id} - {error}')
        new_message_id = new_message_id - 1
```